# SQL Server Bulk Upload in C# no error but not inserting data

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am doing a bulk upload through C#.

It is not a complicated piece of code, but struggling as although the code runs successfully I am not seeing anything on the Database end when I run a query against the destination table.

The table is 
[awsbillingdetailed_w_res_tags]

```
public static string BulkUpload(DataTable dt, string tableName, string connectionString)
     {
          string code = "";

//just resizing datatable so that it makes it smaller for testing. Only 5 rows.
          dt = ReduceDataTableSize(dt, 5);

          dt.TableName = tableName;
          string constr = connectionString;
          try
          {
               using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
               {
                    connection.Open();
                    //CreatingTranscationsothatitcanrollbackifgotanyerrorwhileuploading
                    SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
                    //Start bulkCopy
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection,
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers,
                    trans))
                    {
                         //Fix up default values
                         if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                         {
                                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                              {
                                   dt.Rows[i]["InvoiceId"] = dt.Rows[i]["InvoiceId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["PayerAccountId"] = dt.Rows[i]["PayerAccountId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["LinkedAccountId"] = dt.Rows[i]["LinkedAccountId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["RecordType"] = dt.Rows[i]["RecordType"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["ProductName"] = dt.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["RateId"] = dt.Rows[i]["RateId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["SubscriptionId"] = dt.Rows[i]["SubscriptionId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["PricingplanId"] = dt.Rows[i]["PricingplanId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["UsageType"] = dt.Rows[i]["UsageType"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["PricingplanId"] = dt.Rows[i]["PricingplanId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["Operation"] = dt.Rows[i]["Operation"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["AvailabilityZone"] = dt.Rows[i]["AvailabilityZone"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["ReservedInstance"] = dt.Rows[i]["ReservedInstance"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                      dt.Rows[i]["ItemDescription"] = dt.Rows[i]["ItemDescription"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                      dt.Rows[i]["ResourceId"] = dt.Rows[i]["ResourceId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                      dt.Rows[i]["RecordId"] = dt.Rows[i]["RecordId"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                                   dt.Rows[i]["UsageQuantity"] = dt.Rows[i]["UsageQuantity"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"] = dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"].ToString() == "" ? DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2014) : Convert.ToDateTime((dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"].ToString().Replace("\"", "")));
                                   dt.Rows[i]["usageenddate"] = dt.Rows[i]["usageenddate"].ToString() == "" ? DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2014) : Convert.ToDateTime((dt.Rows[i]["usageenddate"].ToString().Replace("\"", "")));
                                   dt.Rows[i]["UsageQuantity"] = dt.Rows[i]["UsageQuantity"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["BlendedRate"] = dt.Rows[i]["BlendedRate"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["BlendedCost"] = dt.Rows[i]["BlendedCost"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["UnBlendedRate"] = dt.Rows[i]["UnBlendedRate"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                                   dt.Rows[i]["UnBlendedCost"] = dt.Rows[i]["UnBlendedCost"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");


                              }
                         }

                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("InvoiceId", "invoiceid");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PayerAccountId", "payeraccountid");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LinkedAccountId", "linkedaccountid");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("RecordType", "recordtype");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ProductName", "productname");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("RateId", "rateid");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SubscriptionId", "subscriptionid");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PricingplanId", "pricingplanid");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UsageType", "usagetype");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Operation", "operation");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("AvailabilityZone", "availabilityzone");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ReservedInstance", "reservedinstance");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ItemDescription", "itemdescription");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UsageStartDate", "usagestartdate");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UsageEndDate", "usageenddate");
                       bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UsageQuantity", "usagequantity");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BlendedRate", "blendedrate");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BlendedCost", "blendedcost");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UnBlendedRate", "unblendedrate");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UnBlendedCost", "unblendedcost");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("resourceid", "resourceid");

                         //write the data in the "dataTable"
                         bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);

                         code = "Data Processed Successfully";
                    }
               }
               return code;
          }



          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              code = "Error while processing file";
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("EXCEPTION BulkUpload: " + ex.ToString());
          }

          return code;
     }
```

I have also double checked to ensure there were no double quotes or any blank fields for now.

I get no errors, but nothing actually gets into the DB. Any ideas why? Lost a few hours trying to debug this but cannot see any issues. Read plenty of forums but lead me no where. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not committing your transaction. Please review section "Using existing tranactions" @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, just realised that I did not finished/committed the transaction. Funny how we need to write the code , cry for help and then we just suddenly get it.

Essentially missing...

```
trans.Commit();
```

after the bulk upload. Thanks and **apologies for wasting ur time** :)

Comment: Great - well this simple answer helped me along as well.